# How can i get a list in an os.system command, i want to do this so that i can randomise the color the text becomes

Tags: python, operating-system

Here is part of the code, I've done most of it but I cant find a way to implement it into the command.

```
color_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

SHUFFLE(color_list)

os.system('color (color_list[0])')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a f-string like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]

text = f'the first element in l is {l[0]}'
```

text would now be equal to: "the first element in l is 1"

or for your example:

```py
os.system(f'color {color_list[0]}')
```